# Late 70s/80s book about our Earth and a parallel Earth

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, parallel-universe

I vaguely remember a book about parallel worlds, which only animals can see, however, as the story progresses children can see this world as well.
I seem to remember people being able to cross over to the alternative world.

That’s all I can remember but I’d love to know the title so I can re-read it.
I was at secondary school (UK) so it would have been mid 1980s but the book could have been published earlier.

Answer (score 3):

This may be *[On The Flip Side](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/f/nicholas-fisk/on-flip-side.htm)* (1983) by Nicholas Fisk.

> Lettice has the power to communicate with the animals. Is this simply a natural rapport? Or is it something deeper? When a world catastrophe threatens, and animals everywhere are thrown into chaos, Lettice needs all her powers of communication to save the world from a deadly invasion.

Humanity eventually travels to the alternate world due to an invasion of the "Rasters" creatures created or drawn from use of television sets. Animals can perceive them, the presence of which drives the animals into a murderous rage. Eventually, the family dog leads them to an alternate, more primitive, world.

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. And if this is correct, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153839/story-identification-bless-the-beasts-that-bless-us and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15774/childrens-sci-fi-fantasy-with-black-blobs-and-why-cats-stare-at-walls?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a good story for finding this. I'd helped edit the other two answers (and marked one as a dupe) after checking out a copy of the book myself, so I was personally familiar with it. :) Although I'll admit I had to do a Google site search of *site:scifi.stackexchange.com girl dog fuzzyboots creatures* to find where I made that edit since I was neither the querent nor the answerer.